# Dynamically add an auxiliary named router outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to add a `<router-outlet name="param"></router-outlet>`
runtime.

With this code `new RouterOutlet(this.parentOutletMap, this.rox, this.resolver, 'test');`, router-outlet is added but when I call the route there is an error

```
"zone.js:357 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find the outlet test to load 'AuxComponent'"
```

Trying to dynamically add a router-outlet in the main AppComponent, everything works correctly, the error is only in lazy loaded modules.

It seems that `this.router.navigateByUrl` and `this.router.navigate`, only use
the parent outlet map instead of the child map.

[image]

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0W5oZuCTE4dvkNhbvs52?p=preview

GitHub: https://github.com/fabriziodebortoli/dynamic-routing/

Code:

**app.routing**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    {
        path: 'page',
        loadChildren: () => new Promise(function (resolve) {
            (require as any).ensure([], function (require: any) {
                resolve(require('../pages/page.module').default);
            });
        })
    }
];
```

**page.module**

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: '', component: PageComponent },
  {
    path: 'wrap', component: PageComponent, children: [
      { path: 'test', component: AuxComponent, outlet: 'test' }
    ]
  },
]);

@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule, FormsModule, routing],

  // added after Günter comment
  // entryComponents: [RouterOutlet], RouterOutlet is not a Component
  entryComponents: [OutletComponent],

  declarations: [PageComponent],
  exports: [PageComponent]
})
export default class PageModule {}
```

**page.component**

```
@Component({
    template: `Page 
        <hr>
        <button (click)="createRouterOutlet('test')">add</button>
        <button (click)="go()">go</button>
        <div #rox></div>`
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('rox', { read: ViewContainerRef }) rox: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private parentOutletMap: RouterOutletMap,
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.info(this.parentOutletMap);
    }

    createRouterOutlet(name: string) {
        // commented after Günter comment
        // let ro: RouterOutlet = new RouterOutlet(this.parentOutletMap, this.rox, this.resolver, name);
        // console.info(this.parentOutletMap);

        // added after Günter comment
        let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(OutletComponent);
        let cmpRef = this.ros.createComponent(factory);
        console.info(cmpRef);
    }

    go() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/page/wrap/(test:test)');
    }
}
```

Edit: I tryied to wrap RouterOutlet with a custom component OutletComponent but I have the error message "Cannot find the outlet test to load 'AuxComponent'" yet

**outlet.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-outlet',
  template: `<router-outlet [attr.name]="name"></router-outlet>`
})
export class OutletComponent{
  private name: string = 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a component with `new`, this only creates an instance of the components class but without anything that actually makes it an Angular2 component.

```
let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(RouterOutlet);
this.cmpRef = this.rox.createComponent(factory)
/// this.comRef.instance... to access the router outlet instance
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I tryied but I have the error `No component factory found for RouterOutlet`

Comment: Can you please try to add `RouterOutlet` to `entryComponents` of your `@NgModule()`?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Could not compile 'RouterOutlet' because it is not a component.`

Comment: I wasn't aware `RouterOutlet` is a directive and not a component. I'm sure it was a component when I last checked ;-) (it's a while though). I think you need to wrap it with a custom component and then add this component instead.

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-outlet',
      template: `<router-outlet [attr.name]="name"></router-outlet>`
    })
    export class OutletComponent{
      private name: string = 'test';
    }

Comment: Sorry for the last comment... 
I wrapped RouterOutlet in OutletComponent but I have still the error `Cannot find the outlet test to load 'AuxComponent'`

Comment: It doesn't look like a binding to `name` is supported. Please try instead `<router-outlet name="test">` The router outlet uses constructor injection for the `name` attribute and that is only read when the component is created but not when it is later added or updated (which it is with binding). You could create your own implementation that uses an `@Input() name:String` and unregisters from the previous name and registers with the new name. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14ee75924b6ae770115f7f260d720efa8bfb576a/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L54

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125607/discussion-between-fabrizio-de-bortoli-and-gunter-zochbauer).